# Sorting a dictionary of tuples in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples

I know there's tonnes of questions on python sorting lists/dictionaries already, but I can't seem to find one which helps in my case, and i'm looking for the most efficient solution as I'm going to be sorting a rather large dataset.

My data basically looks like this at the moment:

```
a = {'a': (1, 2, 3), 'b': (3, 2, 1)}
```

I'm basically creating a word list in which I store each word along with some stats about it (n, Sigma(x), Sigma(x^2) )

I want to sort it based on a particular stat. So far I've been trying something along the lines of:

```
b = a.items()
b.sort(key = itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

I'm not sure how to control which index it is sorted based on when its effectively a list of tuples of tuples? I guess I effectively need to nest two itemgetter operations but not really sure how to do this.

If there's a better data structure I should be using instead please let me know. Should I perhaps create a small class/struct and then use a lambda function to access a member of the class?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> a = {'a': (1, 2, 3), 'b': (3, 2, 1)}
>>> b = a.items()
>>> b
[('a', (1, 2, 3)), ('b', (3, 2, 1))]
>>> b.sort(key=lambda x:x[1][2])  # sorting by the third item in the tuple
>>> b
[('b', (3, 2, 1)), ('a', (1, 2, 3))]
```

Comment: yes, perfect thanks! However I read somewhere that itemgetter is faster than using a lambda function because its C compiled? If I can't use itemgetter then this solution is fine though.

Comment: Don't worry about performance until you have a working program, complete with unit tests.  If the final, *correct*, program is too slow, then profile it, and optimize the slow bits.

Comment: good point :) I might rewrite it in C if its too slow anyway, thanks for the pointers :)

Comment: How did this work? I get: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sort'`

Answer (score 1):

Names are easier to work with and remember that indices, so I would go with a class:

```
class Word(object):     # don't need `object` in Python 3
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
        self.sigma = (some calculation)
        self.sigma_sq = (some other calculation)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Word(%r)" % self.word
    def __str__(self):
        return self.word
    @property
    def sigma(self):
        return self._sigma
    @sigma.setter               # requires python 2.6+
    def sigma(self, value):
        if not value:
            raise ValueError("sigma must be ...")
        self._sigma = value

word_list = [Word('python'), Word('totally'), Word('rocks')]
word_list.sort(key=lambda w: w.sigma_sq)
```

Comment: thats helpful thanks! Don't suppose you get explicitly define the type of each variable in the class def?

Comment: @technosites If by 'type of each variable' you mean int vs str vs float etc, you can use properties for data validation and whatnot.

Comment: @technosites Added a property example